# Can't change PHP variables in Joomla docker official container

Tags: php, joomla, docker

I am using the joomla official docker container. The problem is that I need to install a component but I receive the following error message:

> Maximum PHP file upload size is too small: This is set in php.ini in
>   both upload_max_filesize and post_max_size settings of your PHP
>   settings

I know that I have to edit this PHP variables in order to install the component. I don't known where is the php.ini file. I already run the `phpinfo()` function and get the path for the php configuration file in

```
/usr/local/etc/php
```

The problem is there are no php.ini file.

How can I change these PHP variables? How to find the `php.ini` file in the official joomla docker container?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to provide your own php.ini file, and load that to the container as a volume.
To do that, add the following flag to the `docker run` command:

```
-v local/path/to/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

If you are using docker compose, update the volumes section of your joomla container definition to look like this:

```
joomla_container:
    ...
    volumes:
      ...
      - local/path/to/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

You definitely shouldn't try to edit the configuration in a running container. If you do this, you'd lose your changes when you update the instance.

Answer (score 1):

Does the **LOADED** configuration file have a path in it?
For example, mine is:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File   C:\Windows\php.ini
```

Comment: The results for the php --ini in my server are: `Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-gd.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-mysqli.ini`

Comment: Okay, so you don't actually have any sort of PHP.ini configured.

In Windows Explorer, open your PHP installation folder, for example C:\PHP.

Choose either the php.ini - development or php.ini - production file, and rename it php.ini.

Save it in the file location it should be found, the root folder, and save it there, then restart your computer/web service, reboot phpinfo and see what it says under loaded config.